# Calculating impact velocity and time with non-uniform acceleration

Tags: time, acceleration, velocity

Here goes:

- imagine a spacecraft with engines shut off in a free fall towards some celestial body x.
- let's say the distance to surface is $100 000$ $\text{meters}$.
- initial vertical velocity is $500$ $\text{m/s}$.
- gravitational pull experienced by the body is obviously given by $F=G \frac {m_1  m_2}{r^2}$.
- acceleration of said craft is calculated as $a = \frac{F}{m}$.

Given constant $F$ and therefore $a$, impact velocity and time are easy to calculate, but how exactly do I solve this, considering  that gravitational pull and  acceleration are constantly changing as we approach the surface?

Key question in [Kinematics with non constant acceleration](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/60492/kinematics-with-non-constant-acceleration) is "To what value does the velocity v of the particle converge to **as x approaches infinity** if the particle starts at some point x0?"

The answer by David H involves the following formula $v_f = \sqrt{\frac{2k}{x_0} + v_0^2}$

In my case x goes from 100000 to 0 m (surface), in other words, there is a clearly defined endpoint which is not equal to infinity. Therefore I do not see how David's formula is applicable in my situation.

Comment: For the special case of starting from rest see the Wikipedia article [Free-fall time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free-fall_time)

Comment: Is not $x_0$ the starting distance from the attracting body;

Comment: The proposed duplicate isn't a duplicate because it doesn't give $r(t)$ for the falling body. Surprisingly I can't find an answer here that gives this equation.

Comment: Correct solution is the following: $v_f = \sqrt{{(G}{(m1 + m2)} (\frac{1}{y} - \frac{1}{y_0})) {2} + {v_0^2}}$

Where: 

$V_f$ - impact velocity;
$y$ - radius of the celestial body;
$y_0$ - distance to surface;
$v_0$ - initial velocity of the spacecraft.

The difference between this and David's formula is small but still significant  for an inexperienced person.